# Cannot read value after getting queried by model.find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

```
exports.start = async (message) => {

    let check = await profile.find({userID:message.author.id});
    console.log(check);
    console.log(check.userID);

    try{
        let userAdd = new profile({
            userID: message.author.id,
            ServerID: message.guildId,
            level: 1,
        });
        const savedUser = await userAdd.save();
        message.channel.send(embedbuilder(`${message.author} has joined!`))
    } catch(err) {
        message.channel.send(embedbuilder("Error joining the event"))
    }
}
```

**"console.log(check);"** but when i try to read a value inside it by **console.log(check.userID)** it says undefined.

here the output

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` returns **array of documents** so the fields `userID` does not exist on an array.

If you are sure that response will return exactly one document then use `findOne`.

Answer (score 0):

`find` returns an array. You have to use `.forEach` to get the items in array or use `findOne` to get an object

```
let check = await profile.find({userID:message.author.id});
console.log(check);
check.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.userID)
})
```

Or

```
let check = await profile.findOne({userID:message.author.id});
console.log(check);
console.log(check.userID);
```